# How to determine if two host names are in the same domain

Tags: regex, domain-name

How to write code to decide if two host name in same domain ? 
like :

  `www.example.com`
  and
  `login.eample.com`
  in same domain

  `www.example.com.us`
  and
  `login.exmaple.com.us`
  in same domain

  `x105.www.example.com`
  and
  `login.example.com`
  in same domin

and even `www.example.com` and `login.example.com.us` in same domain if possible

Comment: Why would `www.example.com` and `login.example.com.us` be "in the same domain"?

Comment: Same for the others excepting x105.www.example.com and login.example.com - are there typos?

Comment: But example.com and example.com.us aren't the same? Also when you say code do you mean regexp (like your tag), if not, what language are you trying to do it with?

Comment: deceze is right, those are not in the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Using perl since no language was mentioned, pardon any rust...

```
([^.]+\.[^.]+$)
```

that regex would give you the domain of the first instance as a captured string ($1).  You could use that captured string, if this was say perl, like this to see if they match.

```
$firstHostName =~ /([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/;
if ($secondHostName =~ /$1$/) {
    print "same domain";
}
```

Comment: Your expression only looks at two elements of a domain name. That would make every domain in the `.co.uk` domain into the 'same' domain, which the companies in the UK might object to. I think you need to strip the first element off the FQDN and what's left is the domain name. Of course, even assuming that the typos are fixed, that means that the question's examples 3 and 4 would not be in the same domain (number 3 because `www.example.com` is not necessarily the same domain as the `example.com`). Alternatively, you have to know how many components to analyze. US city web sites are interesting.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us) for a discussion of URLs such as [`http://www.ci.sweeny.tx.us/`](http://www.ci.sweeny.tx.us/) where host names in the 'same domain' would all end with `.ci.sweeny.tx.us`, which would require 4 levels of domain to be the same at the end.